# Gantt using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I would like to draw following picture in latex.
I would like to have a suggestion if this could be easily possible by `pgfgantt` package? Or should I use `tikz` to draw this kind of diagram?
In `pgfgantt`, it is produce some top line, which I would not like to have. Plus in addition it has a box like borders, whereas I would prefer the diagram to look like below.

Can anyone give me suggestion, how can I do this quickly?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could draw some simple diagram using tikz -

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Axis
    \draw (-0.5,0) -- (6.0,0);
    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (0,3.0);
    % Tasks
    \node (rect) at (1,1) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$A$};
    \node (rect) at (3,1) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$B_0$};
    \node (rect) at (2,1) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$B_1$};
    \node (rect) at (2,2) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$B_2$};
    \node (rect) at (3,2) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$C_2$};
    \node (rect) at (4,2) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$C_1$};
    \node (rect) at (4,1) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$C_0$};
    \node (rect) at (5,1) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm] {$D_0$};

    % Annotations
    \node at (5.75,-0.25) {Time};
    \node at (-0.35,1) {P1};
    \node at (-0.35,2) {P2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest that you also make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for an answer, a compilable code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, you can shorten the code by using `\foreach`

Comment: In addition to hpesoj626 comment, you can also use `styles` in order to not repeat any time the options `draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=1cm`.